# Intersection of path-connected sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, path-connected

Let $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be two path-connected sets. Is it true that $A \cap B$ is also path-connected?

(A subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is path-connected if every pair of points in $A$ can be joined by a path in $A$).

Intuitively, I think that the answer is no. I don't know how to disprove this though. Can someone please help me with this exercise? I am having trouble finding a counterexample.

Comment: Draw two intersecting horseshoes.

Comment: No; take a circle and a straight line that intersects it; they are both path-connected but their intersection (two distinct points) is not.

Answer (score 4):

Take the two (closed) halves of a circle. Each of them is path-connected, but their intersection isn't even connected.

Comment: Wouldn't their intersection just be the line separating the halves? Isn't that path-connected?

Comment: A circle isn't solid.

Comment: No: the intersection consists of two points only.

Comment: How can I show the two half circles are path-wise connected?

Comment: A closed interval is path-connected, right?! And an half-circle is homeomorphic to a closed interval, right?!

Answer (score 4):

Visual proof of the answer by Jose' Carlos Santos:

[image]